# Java8 - Convert a very large XML input into JSON (with an extra attribute)

Tags: java, stax

I would like to transform a huge XML into JSON. Each time a specific XML-tag is recognized, I would like to convert the XML-part of the tag to JSON **AND** I would like to add a simple counter to it.

Important is that the input XML is very large, so putting it into a memomry JSON tree is not possible.

SO ... `<xml><car>...</car><car>...</car>...`

is converted to

```
{"number":2,"car":{"name":"car1"}}
{"number":3,"car":{"name":"car2"}}
```

Comment: You should either write an XSLT for the transformer, instead of using the identity transformer, or you should do it yourself with the StAX reader you're using. Don't do a mix of the two.

Comment: Is the numbering local or global? For nested objects? For multiple relations at the same level?

Comment: Numbering is all on the 'highest' level: so on car. Please explain about mixing the two. I search for good (realistic) examples of Transformer.transform, but could not find one.

Comment: See e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials - Transforming XML Data with XSLT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html)

Comment: Thank you!! I will study this. Is it possible also the Stax approach? Please provide this as answer.

Comment: Sounds like a really bad attempt at mixing technologies for purposes they are not meant to be used for. Why not simple read the XML into a tree or object graph and write it back out as JSON?

Comment: Yes, i know i know. I had to review similar code and I could not understand why doing this. Making a tree is not possible, because due to the huge size of the input file. So chunking it has to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andreas I finally found the solution for processing a huge XML file and converting the matches xml-elements to JSON.

```
String testCars = "<root><car><name>car1</name></car><other><something>Unknown</something></other><car><name>car2</name></car></root>";
String startElement = "car";
int volgnummer = 1;
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
try {
    XMLStreamReader streamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(testCars));
    streamReader.nextTag();
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
    t.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
    streamReader.nextTag();
    while ( streamReader.isStartElement() ||
          ( ! streamReader.hasNext() && 
            streamReader.nextTag() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT)) {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        t.transform(new StAXSource(streamReader), result);
        JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(writer.toString());
        jsonObject.put("sequence", ++volgnummer);
        System.out.println("XmlChunkToJson: " + jsonObject.toString());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <car>
    <name>car1</name>
  </car>
  <other>
    <something>Unknown</something>
  </other>
  <car>
    <name>car2</name>
  </car>
</root>
```

Output JSON:

```
XmlChunkToJson: {"sequence":2,"car":{"name":"car1"}}
XmlChunkToJson: {"sequence":3,"other":{"something":"Unknown"}}
XmlChunkToJson: {"sequence":4,"car":{"name":"car2"}}
```